# Secure subfloor underwall between joists

Tags: bathroom, subfloor

I jumped to quickly into cutting out subfloor in my bathroom and I am now trying to figure out how resolve the issue and get the new plywood in place and secured properly.

I cut the sub floor to as close as I could to the wall but that leave me with a gap just over 4" from the joist. I have completed access from below but I don't want to have to rip up anything on the opposite side of the wall.

My thoughts are to just pick up a 2x6 and lay it even with the floor to have somewhere to anchor the board. I am just not sure if that is the best way.

I will attempt to post a picture from below.

https://goo.gl/photos/hTJBbEiASHbKxr28A

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**

I let the photo lull me into a sense that the OP had more access to the joists than what is actually accessible. I did indicate what I think the answer is, in the final sentence of my final answer as an option...

You obviously can't leave plywood cantilevered out in space like that, and there's no way to butt one piece of plywood up against another in open air and have it support a load. The gap is also too big to sister the existing joist with a 2x4 and create a lip to support the plywood.

So I believe your only viable option is to use metal joist hangers and install short perpendicular joists between the two existing prefab joists. My first instinct was to suggest 2x6's for this, but I looked at an online joist load calculator and it exposed my tendency to overbuild. 2x4's are probably fine. (example:  http://www.awc.org/codes-standards/calculators-software/spancalc). I'd put them on standard 16" centers so you don't get any sag in the plywood subfloor. Then you could lay a strip of plywood down across those new joists, and the new joists will support everything.

You might have to work a little to tap/pound the ears on the joist hangers between the left joist and the subfloor above it, or find hangers designed to be mounted to a flat surface without a top ledge.

[image]
[image]

The only other options that would work would seem to involve demo work on the wall above the left joist.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**:

If I'm seeing that picture correctly, you have full open access to everything from above and below.

You want to set the cutting depth on a circular saw so that it just barely cuts through the plywood, and do a rip cut from above, straight down the middle of the joist/truss on the left (do NOT notch into the top of that truss). Then tear up the plywood, and lay new plywood down spanning both joists.

Another option might be to create short joists between the existing ones, perpendicular to them.

Comment: I think the uncut portion of the plywood is under a wall, based on what the OP described in the question. Your answer is what the OP *should* have done.

Comment: I agree there is definitely some should have done there and I realize that. Also, the joist go the left I don't have access to. The joist on the right is the furthest joist I have top access to. I was thinking about perpendicular board from joist to joist. Not sure if this changes anything but the current subfloor is TG.

Comment: Yeah... kind of what I was thinking. If so, the picture isn't sufficient, and the short joists is probably what's called for.

Comment: @kwelch, perpendicular boards from joist to joist is the "short joists" option from the last sentence in my (original) answer. I'd put those on 16" centers, just like any other joist, and hang them with good metal joist hangers.

Comment: I definitely agree. Are 2x4 sufficient for the short joists?

Comment: @kwelch I instinctively said 2x6's in my revised answer, but then I went to an online joist load calculator (not a definitive source, so do your own due diligence), and it's saying 2x4's made out of Alaska Cedar (the default material in the calculator) are good for a 5' span. And it looks like the existing joists are on 16" centers. I'm thinking 2x4's are probably fine. **Standard Disclaimer:** I'm a guy who probably has a tendency to overbuild. I figure if humans in the future want to get rid of something I built, they can demo it, but it's darn well still going to be standing... ;-)

Comment: @Craig Typical stud grade 2x4s are going to be pine (or similar), not cedar.

Comment: @Tester101 Sure, and I for one sincerely appreciate your attention to detail!! Actually, I'd bet you $5 they're just as likely to be fir. Given that cedar 2x4's are apparently good for a 5'11" span, I presumed pine/fir wouldn't be different enough to matter when you're talking about a 16" span. Actually, I just checked that calculator again, and fir 2x4's are good for a 6'7" span. White pine 2x4's are apparently good for a 5'8" span. ;-)